# How to update username and password on git remote?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch

Though I can git fetch/pull/push on eclipse, but when I git fetch on GitBash, I got error as below, how can I set id/pw on remote?

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://abc.xyz.co.jp/projects/project.git/'
```

Comment: Git (i.e., the `git` command you run locally on your machine) cannot set your ID and/or password on any *other* machine. You need to find some way to tell that other machine to do it. All your local Git can do is supply any user name and/or password that you provide to your local Git.

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
git credentials --help
```

in Git Bash, you should get the documentation that will help you. It popped up in a browser window for me and explains how to set the username and password.